# How to pass state into a dependency chain using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, actor, chain

I have a number of service classes in a dependency chain (Service A depends on Service B, which depends on Service C etc.); their behaviors are determined by a common parameter (CountryCode), the possible supported country being defined at runtime.

Note: Actors can be scaled into multiple instances (different threads), and an event will only be processed by a single actor, services below are transient (although I can look into changing this if needed).

At the moment I have something like so:

```
//This application flow starts off with this class
public class ActorExample
{
    private IServiceOne _serviceOne; //Has dependent service

    public async Task ProcessAsync(Event event)
    {
        //This value needs to be passed to _serviceOne and any children
        //but we only know its value at runtime.
        event.CountryCode; 
    }
}

public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne
{
    private IServiceTwo _serviceTwo; //Has another nested dependency

    //Implementation here varies depending on event.CountryCode
    public async Task DoSomething()
}

public class ServiceTwo : IServiceTwo
{
    //Implementation here varies depending on event.CountryCode
    public async Task DoSomething()
}
```

I thought i could perhaps use generics with the services so passing the country code like so:

```
public class ServiceTwo<TCountryCode> : IServiceTwo<TCountryCode>
```

But because we only have the value at runtime this is not possible, especially when injecting in the services.

Another solution is to inject the services with a dependent CountryCode as null and later populate in the constructors, something like:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IActor>().ImplementedBy<Actor>()
         .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("CountryCode", null));
```

however this seems messy and cumbersome especially if the nesting goes quite deep.

If all else fails i was perhaps considering setting the store before calling an functions but i would have to do this for every function eg:

```
_serviceOne.SetCountry(CountryCode).DoSomething();
```

Note: we are using castle for IOC

Answer (score 3):

Since the country code is runtime data, then you should pass it as a parameter in your service methods.

If this is not acceptable, i.e. it does not make sense (e.g. from a conceptual perspective) to change the method signature to contain the country code, then you can store the country code inside a State Holder (an object whose only responsibility is to know the "current" country code) and have the object that needs to know the "current" country code have access (via a dependency) on this State Holder.

This pattern is explained in details with an example in the "Controlling shared state: The State Holder pattern" section of this article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1367/data-encapsulation-large-csharp-applications

Comment: Thanks for the reply, holding the state is a possibility.. however the actor is going to receive x number of events containing varying CountryCodes. I would then have to store this in some sort of state machine and somehow manage its removal when the event has been disposed (which seems very tricky). I fear this solution might open up another can of worms.

Comment: @FishFingers, can you provide the relevant details in the question? e.g. Does a single request (A Call from A to B to C...) run on a single thread?

Comment: @FishFingers, if a single event will be handled by a single thread all the way down, then all you need to do is create an implementation of the State Holder pattern that is thread local. You can use the ThreadLocal class from the .NET framework.

Comment: @YacoubMassad You have consider one **very import** point though: a variable that is set at runtime will certainly at some point be NULL (no matter if you wrap it into a container or not). There's no point around. So, it's the programer's responsbility to make sure that this variable is first set, before it's called by a consumer. It's the tradeoff you have to accept, when going with DI frameworks, since a normal constructor chain will force you to specify a temporal chain, which guarantees a "happens-before" relationship

Comment: @cobby, I wrap the state with a special type so that I get a readable exception message when the state object contains no value (e.g. NULL) which indicates that there is a programming error. I am not sure I understand how using a DI framework can fix this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Oh, that was the point of my comment. I think you can't fix it with a DI framework. When you set the State Holder as a dependency in a consumer, there's no guarantee that the state was already set at RT. You have to manually assure that, when the state is requested by the consumer (or e.g. throw an exception). Point is, you'll only know that at runtime. However, constructing objects through a classical constructor chain guarantees a "happens-before" relationship at compile time. Latter avoids [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/)

Comment: @cobby, right. So its a tradeoff then. One thought I have about this though is that when you pass a parameter a few levels down, you need to make sure that everyone is passing it as is. There is a chance that programmers make an error and not pass the parameter correctly, e.g., pass null instead of the argument they receive? or maybe manipulate the argument? If only two objects (the object that sets the value and the objects that uses it) know about this state, then you need to only make sure that these two objects have no programming errors.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a typed factory:

```
public interface IServiceOneFactory
{
    IServiceOne Create(CountryCode countryCode);
}

public class ServiceOne : IServiceOne
{
    public ServiceOne(IServiceTwo servicetwo, CountryCode countryCode)
    {
    }
}

public class ActorExample
{
    private raedonly IServiceOneFactory factory;

    public ActorExample(IServiceOneFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task ProcessAsync(Event event)
    {
        var serviceOne = this.factory.Create(event.CountryCode);
    }
}
```

The same for ServiceTwo...

And the registration:

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(Component.For<IServiceOneFactory>().AsFactory();
kernel.Register(Component.For<IServiceOne>().ImplementedBy<ServiceOne>());
kernel.Register(Component.For<IServiceTwo>().ImplementedBy<ServiceTwo>());
kernel.Register(Component.For<IActor>().ImplementedBy<Actor>());
```

More info here:

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md

**EDIT:**
To avoid code duplication you can create generic factory:

```
public interface IServiceFactory<T>
{
    T Create(CountryCode countryCode);
}

public ActorExample(IServiceFactory<IServiceOne> factory)
{
    this.factory = factory;
}

kernel.Register(Component.For(typeof(IServiceFactory<>)).AsFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, my issue with this solution is that my service will be coupled with a factory (1 to 1) which means every time i have a service i have to create a factory. I currently have 9 different services (I can see this number growing). This is going to add a lot of factory noise to the codebase.

Comment: Then instead of having CountryCode in constructor, pass it through the method call DoSomething().

Comment: Yup this is my final resort, im hoping there is another elegant way of dealing with this.

Comment: From your code sample it seems to be a best way, but if you still need to have a parameter in the constructor and you want to reduce the number of factories than create generic one.

Comment: Could you please please expand on creating a generic factory? I did actually give this a shot but because we only know the CountryCode type at runtime using generics coupled with dependency injection in my view is not possible.